# How to read/write unsigned array to ifstream/ostream in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, ifstream, ostream

I have below code :

```
/*write to file*/
std::basic_ofstream<unsigned short> out(path, std::ios::out);
unsigned short *arr = new  unsigned short[500];
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{ 
    arr[i] = i;
}

out.write(arr, 500);
out.close();

/*read from file*/
unsigned short * data = new unsigned short[500];
std::basic_ifstream<unsigned short> rfile(path);
rfile.read(data, 500);
rfile.close();
```

Simply i write a unsigned short array to file then i read that but read values are right until index 25 in array and after that the values are 52685.
Where is the problem?

Comment: `out.write(arr, 500);` is dang close, but `write` wants bytes and not a count of array elements. `out.write(arr, 500* sizeof(arr[0]));` should do it for you. Ditto for `read`.

Comment: Mind you, if you're getting bad values at 25, either your array is 50 elements long, your compiler uses a fantastically huge `short`, or there is something else going on that I'm not seeing.

Comment: i checked it , it doesn't work.a strange thing is it saves array until 255 in file

Comment: Ack. 255 tells the tale. File is finding an eof character in the file and exiting . `out(path, std::ios::out);` needs to specify binary read and write. Try `out(path, std::ios::binary);`. Same for `read`. Don't need the `std::ios::out` as it is implied by creating an `ofstream`.

Comment: now read is right , but write is still wrong :)

Comment: Just noticed `std::basic_ofstream<unsigned short>`. Is this deliberate? Why not good ol' `std::ofstream`?

Comment: I also tried std::ofstream but it converts u short values to signed chars and array is right until 9

Comment: This has lead down a few interesting paths. I've never tried to use a `std::basic_ofstream<unsigned short>` before. And frankly I can't get it to work. The `write` fails every time, and I'm not awake enough at this hour to fully unravel what's missing. But if you `std::ofstream out("test.bin", std::ios::binary);` and cast the array to `char*` on the read and write you should be back in the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use the template parameter of `basic_ofstream` with a non character type (i.e. `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` or `char32_t`). For the most part, just use `ofstream` (and `ifstream` for input).

The fact that your input stops after the 25th character is actually a clue that you are probably on Windows, where ASCII character 26, the [Substitute character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character), is used to indicate end of file for text streams. You are trying to read and write binary data though, so you need to open your file with the binary flag.

```
/*write to file*/
std::ofstream out(path, std::ios::binary);
unsigned short *arr = new  unsigned short[500];
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) { 
    arr[i] = i;
}

out.write((char const*)arr, 500 * sizeof(arr[0]));
out.close();

/*read from file*/
unsigned short * data = new unsigned short[500];
std::ifstream rfile(path, std::ios::binary);
rfile.read((char*)data, 500 * sizeof(data[0]));
rfile.close();
```

Also interesting to note, 52685, in hexadecimal is 0xCDCD. This is the value which Visual C++ (and maybe some other compilers) uses to fill uninitialized memory in debug mode. Your array isn't receiving this value from the file, this is the value which was inserted there when your memory was allocated.